# Install TP-Archer 1300 mini on Ubuntu 20.10

Tags: drivers, wireless, dkms, tp-link, 20.10

Tried this

```
git clone https://github.com/cilynx/rtl88x2bu.git
cd rtl88x2bu
VER=$(sed -n 's/\PACKAGE_VERSION="\(.*\)"/\1/p' dkms.conf)
sudo rsync -rvhP ./ /usr/src/rtl88x2bu-${VER}
sudo dkms add -m rtl88x2bu -v ${VER}
sudo dkms build -m rtl88x2bu -v ${VER}
sudo dkms install -m rtl88x2bu -v ${VER}
sudo modprobe 88x2bu
```

getting error

```
Kernel preparation unnecessary for this kernel.  Skipping...

Building module:
cleaning build area...
make -j8 KERNELRELEASE=5.8.0-25-generic KVER=5.8.0-25-generic src=/usr/src/rtl88x2bu-5.6.1...(bad exit status: 2)
ERROR (dkms apport): binary package for rtl88x2bu: 5.6.1 not found
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 5.8.0-25-generic (x86_64)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/rtl88x2bu/5.6.1/build/make.log for more information.
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
cd rtl88x2bu
sudo dkms add .
sudo dkms install -m rtl88x2bu -v 5.6.1
```

Reboot

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/Vertabreak/rtl88x2bu

This worked for me. Credit goes to vertabreak, who worked to get my generic WiFi adapter that uses the rtl88x2bu to work. Make sure you delete any old rtl88x2bu folders and reboot before you install.